# Display a new image based on image choices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a form in HTML using radio buttons for options.  The radio buttons need to be individual clickable thumbnail images (so no browser style radio buttons will be seen, and each radio button is different).  There will be 3 groups of radio buttons, each with 3 options.

These need to combine at the end to display a larger main image elsewhere on the page, based on the options the user selected.

I want the main image to change dynamically, as the user selects each option. - I don't want a form with a submit button at the end.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

The code I have so far is:

```
    <style>
label {display:block;}
.radio {
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;                   
}
.checked {opacity: 1;}
#single {background: url(a.jpg);}
#double {background: url(b.jpg);}
#none {background: url(c.jpg);}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio].radio-image').each(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        $(this).hide().after('<a class="newrad" href="#"><div class="radio" id="' + id + '"></div></a>');
    });
    $('.newrad').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $check = $(this).prev('input');
        $('.newrad div').attr('class', 'radio');
        $(this).find('div').addClass('checked');
        $('input[type=radio].radio-image').attr('checked', false);
        $check.attr('checked', true);
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:radio[name=wardrobe]").change(function() {
            if (this.value == "a") {
                $("#imgOne").attr(
                    'src', 'a.jpg'
                );
            }
            else {
                $("#imgOne").attr(
                    'src', 'b.jpg'                   
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>


<form>
 <label><input type="radio" class="radio-image" name="wardrobe" id="single"    value="a" />A</label>
 <label><input type="radio" class="radio-image" name="wardrobe" id="double"  value="b" />B</label>
 <label><input type="radio" class="radio-image" name="wardrobe" id="none" value="c" />C</label>
 </form>


<img id="imgOne" />


</body>
```

It's only a partial code, for the first set of options, I used it as a starting point.

I managed to get thumbnails as radio buttons, which work great.  And I managed to get normal radio buttons to swap an image.  But I can't get both working together.

Comment: What do you have already?

Comment: can you give your current code, research examples or something please?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you are on the right track. Although I am a little confused on the functionality of hiding the button and replacing it with an  tag, I believe what you want is to make thumbnail images have the functionality of radio buttons. All you have to do is replace your current

```
<input type="radio" class="radio-image" name="wardrobe" id="single" value="a" />
```

with

```
<img src="a.jpg" class="radio-image" data-ref="a"/>
```

and change your jQuery to allow for these new images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.radio-image').click(function() {
        $("img.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $("#imgOne").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-ref") + ".jpg");
    });
});
```

and the css

```
img{
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.selected {
    border: 1px solid #00c;
}
```

The trick is that your images just need to sit there. Let jQuery do the heavy lifting. I hope this helps.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much.  That has solved the first bit of the code, which is great.  I now just need to work out how to incorporate this code with the other 2 sets of radio buttons to affect the main image. - Do you have any ideas please? - I've tried appending data-ref with a number 2 in a separate form, but the selector will only allow me to select one across all options.

Comment: I think that you just need to add two more images:

    <img src="b.jpg" class="radio-image" data-ref="b"/>
    <img src="c.jpg" class="radio-image" data-ref="c"/>

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got that to work just fine.  I want to add in another 2 sets of 3 radio buttons. Eg. set 1 - choice a, b, or c. Set 2 - choice d, e or f and set 3 - choice g, h or i.  Then the result is built like this adg.jpg, adh.jpg, aeh.jpg, etc